# Encode json data with two tables using join

Tags: php, json, mysqli

Does anyone know my problem with my code?  I have two tables which are sales_details and sales_payment. Sales details where you can see all the details and the other table is for payment info/transaction. Sales details have the primary key and the sales_payment table have the FK. To combine all the data I used the inner join statement.

Here's an example of my data. I run a sample query using join. All of the pictures are the result of the query. I cropped it because I can't take a long screenshot in landscape mode.

**Sales Details Table:**
[image: tbl_sales_details]

**Sales Detail Table (Continuation):**
[image: tbl_sales_details1]

**Sales Payment Table:**
[image: tbl_sales_payment]

This what I've tried:

```
public function get_payment_info_by_id($payment_info_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_sales_details AS tsd INNER JOIN tbl_sales_payments AS tsp ON tsp.sales_id = tsd.sales_id WHERE tsd.sales_id = $payment_info_id");
    
    echo json_encode($query->fetch_object());
}
```

**Returned json data:**

[image: json_data]

As you can see the JSON data. It didn't return all the data in tbl_sales_payment.

I want to return my json data like this:

```
{
    sales_balance: "4601.60"
    sales_company: ""
    sales_cp: ""
    sales_date: "2021-01-12 01:26:33"
    sales_discount: "0.00"
    sales_dr: "5768"
    sales_height: "8.00"
    sales_id: "3"
    sales_media: "Sticker on Sintra"
    sales_net_amount: "8601.60"
    sales_particulars: "Authorized Personnel Only"
    sales_po: "100549"
    sales_price_unit: "4.00"
    sales_qty: "15.00"
    sales_si: "1794"
    sales_so: "1234"
    sales_total: "7680.00"
    sales_total_area: "128.00"
    sales_unit: "in"
    sales_vat: "921.60"
    sales_width: "16.00"
    "payments": [
      {
        payment_id: "3"
        payment_amount: "1000.00"
        payment_date: "2021-01-15"
        payment_remarks: ""
      },
      {
        payment_id: "4"
        payment_amount: "1000.00"
        payment_date: "2021-01-18"
        payment_remarks: ""
      },
      {
        payment_id: "5"
        payment_amount: "2000.00"
        payment_date: "2021-01-29"
        payment_remarks: ""
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wujeck,

try this,

```
public function get_payment_info_by_id($payment_info_id) {
    $return_data = [];
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_sales_details AS tsd INNER JOIN tbl_sales_payments AS tsp ON tsp.sales_id = tsd.sales_id WHERE tsd.sales_id = $payment_info_id");
    
    while ($obj = $query->fetch_object()) {
        $return_data[] = $obj;
    }

    echo json_encode($return_data);
}
```

Comment: Looks good! Is it possible to not repeat the data in the sales_details table to avoid redundancy?

Comment: Possible but its easier by code. Like this, 
`$tsd_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_sales_details WHERE sales_id=$payment_info_id"); 
$tsd_result = $tsd_query ->fetch_object(); 
$tsp_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_sales_payments WHERE sales_id=$payment_info_id"); 
while ($obj = $tsp_query->fetch_object()) {
        $paymetns[] = $obj;
}
$tsd_result->payments = $payments;
echo json_encode($tsd_result);`